# Hiding overflowing element based on its height

Tags: javascript, dom, size, web-frontend

I'm writing (using pure JavaScript = no JQuery) a custom control which is a container that collapses it's contents when they span multiple lines and show only the first one. When you click a button in the control (down arrow), the container expands all of it's content. **If content spans only 1 line, I don't show the button at all** and it behaves as a regular container.

The 2 pictures below show the control collapsed (upper one) and expanded (bottom one).

[image: Control collapsed]

[image: Control expanded]

The problem I face is how do I know when to show the button and when not = how to detect if content is multiline or spans only a single line. My approach would be getting the height of the element, then collapsing it and seeing if the height changed (if it did, then it must be multiline).

The problem with that approach is inside my function `createCollapsingPanel()` the element I'm creating hasn't been yet appended to the DOM - the function returns the element, which will only then be appended to DOM (illustrated by *Architecture 1* below). If that would concern only that 1 function, I could of course move appending inside the function (*Architecture 2* below). Unfortunately that is the way I wrote all of my functions (they return elements, which are only then appended into parent elements in the outer functions that called them) and so that would mean re-writing other parent functions that in the end call this one, in general my whole architecture of functions.

---

*Architecture 1*

```
function createOuterElement() {
  var outerElement = document.createElement(...);

  outerElement.appendChild(createInnerElement());
  /* Do other things with outerElement */

  return outerElement;
}

function createInnerElement() {
  var innerElement = document.createElement(...);

  /* Do things with innerElement */

  return innerElement;
}
```

*Architecture 2*

```
function createOuterElement(parentElement) {
  var outerElement = document.createElement(...);

  parentElement.appendChild(outerElement);
  createInnerElement(outerElement);
  /* Do other things with outerElement */
}

function createInnerElement(parentElement) {
  var innerElement = document.createElement(...);

  parentElement.appendChild(innerElement);
  /* Do other things with innerElement */
}
```

---

**Main Question**

Any ideas on how to deal with that in my current architecture (*Architecture 1*)? Maybe there's an event I could attatch to the control element and it would get invoked after the element is inserted into DOM and browser styles are calculated for it?

**Additional Question**

Is writing functions in *Architecture 1* considered a bad practice? I'm pretty new to non-basic JavaScript, so am unsure what good practices are.

Comment: Do you want to use "Pure JavaScript" or is a library like jQuery fine for your purposes?

Comment: I'm using pure JavaScript in my project. Though it's always good to know any solution, even in JQuery.

Comment: **Additional Question**: i would construct the whole tree before inserting into the dom. this can be achieved with both *architectures*. in case of *architecture 2* `parentElement.appendChild(...` should be the last call of the `createOuterElement` function.

Comment: @dreamlab To construct a tree before insterting it into the DOM (as you recommended), *Architecture 1* seems a more elegant solution to me - every function has smaller scope, being unaware of what their parents are, where and how it will be appended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could always have the inner container be multiline and just clip it with the outer container.

on the outer container use:

- `overflow: hidden`
- `height:`*somevalue*

on the inner container use:

- `position: absolute`
- `height: auto`

put the `span`'s inside the inner container.

you can now measure the inner containers height independently from the outer ones.

Comment: I don't understand how that would solve my problem. In fact I'm using the same CSS to create my control, only I'm not using `position: absolute` on the inner container. The problem is with the button which I'd like to show when the element has multiple lines and hide it when it has only a single line of items.

Comment: no. you still need to measure after appending to the dom. either by a hidden measerContainer, a function after inserting to dom, or a MutationObserver. i would recommend the function after inserting everything.

Comment: So in fact this solution is the same solution as before - calling a measuring function after the whole structure is in the DOM.

Comment: the javascript is the same. although the html/css allows to not have to resize the outer container to measure the inner container, like you asked: *My approach would be getting the height of the container, then collapsing it and seeing if the height changed (if it did, then it must be multiline).*

Comment: I used the wrong words I think - I meant collapsing the child element, not the parent container. Sorry. But in general my problem lies in JavaScript so both answers lead to the same JavaScript solutions.

Comment: I implemented the solution with MutationObservers but it works only partially. Some elements report correct height, but some doesn't and I still have expand/collapse buttons appearing where they shouldn't appear. It works alright when I delay the measuring of height by at least 200ms, but I don't treat setTimeout with hard-coded value as a working solution (it will work on my browser but doesn't have to on other ones). Do you know why browser can still calculate the height of element in a wrong way after already inserting it into DOM? @dreamlab

Comment: have you tried with a function after inserting? i wouldn't be sure that the observers are reliable.

Comment: No, I have only tried observers. But they work - the measuring function gets invoked after element is in the DOM. Now I have another problem, which is that some styles seem to be not fully calculated soon after the insertion. For most elements the return `height`'s values are alright, but for few of them they are too big. If I delay that calculation by 200ms, every value gets calculated properly. Is there a way to force full calculation of the styles for particular element or some event that would get invoked after those styles are calculated by the browser?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80225/discussion-between-dreamlab-and-robert).

Answer (score 1):

you can use a hidden container in the dom to measure element sizes. the hidden container can be a simple div in the dom like:

```
   ...
   <body>
      <div id="measurementContainer" style="display:none;"></div>
```

a measuring function could than:

1. append the element to the measurement container (`div`)
2. measure the element
3. and remove it from the measurement container again

for example:

```
    function measureElementWidth(element) {
       var measurementContainer = document.getElementById(measurementContainer);
       measurementContainer.appendChild(element);

       var width = element.clientWidth;

       measurementContainer.removeChild(element);

       return width;
}
```

---

alternatively you can use [MutationObservers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and get notified if an element is added to the dom. check if all needed browsers [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver) this.

---

or even simpler: just call your sizing function after you append your elements to the dom.

Comment: Yeah, now I get it. Thanks. Pretty neat trick. The problem is that measurement container doesn't exactly stimulate the parent container at which the element will be appended in the end. The size after appending it to the target parent can be different because of styles that are applied on the parent. For example in my case the width of the parent isn't 100% of the page (and it's the width that does imply if the container will span multiple lines or only a single one).

Comment: in that case. get the target containers width and height first and set it manually on the measuring container: `measuringContainer.style.width = target.clientWidth + 'px'`. do the same for height.

Comment: But as I said the architecture of my function iis as illustrated in my example *Architecture 1*. The effect of that is when creating the child, the parent also hasn't been appended to DOM yet and so I can't calculate it's size. I could of course re-write those functions to the *Architecture 2*, but first want to be sure that is either absolutely necessary or it is a really bad practice to write functions in *Architecture 1*.

Comment: you need to call the sizing function after you insert the outerElement. before that just let the innerElements be as they are.

Comment: I could call it after the parent has been inserted into the DOM. Still (because of my function architecture) that would happen only after the most outer parent has been inserted into DOM. The problem there is I don't have any easy access to the panels, which are buried really deep then. I could of course store somewhere the references to all panels, but this approach felt inelegant to me. I thought maybe I could append some events to the panels, that would be called after they are already in DOM (something like `AfterAppendedToDOM`). Is there any such event you know about that I could here?

Comment: see second paragraph: MutationObservers